# How to create custom Twitter Widget with C# in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter

i need to create my own twitter widget in my asp.net-c# website.How to get tweets from Twitter and Clear concern about the authorization properties.

Comment: It's worth noting that Twitter is about to move to OAuth for authentication, see this post: http://blog.twitter.com/2010/08/twitter-applications-and-oauth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several very good .NET libraries for communicating with Twitter.

I would recommend starting with Twitterizer (http://twitterizer.net).

You might also consider TwitterVB (http://twittervb.codeplex.com), which is a library that I developed for .NET.

Both of these libraries have had stable implementaitons of OAuth for some time.